# How disable widget?

Tags: uibinder, gwt-2.2

I use GWT Editors framework for data binding.
I have next code:

**AAAView.java**

```
public interface AAAView extends Editor<AAA> {

public interface Presenter {
}

public interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<AAA, AAAViewImpl> {
}

void setPresenter(Presenter presenter);

Driver initializeDriver();

Widget asWidget();
```

}

**AAAViewImpl.java**

```
public class AAAViewImpl extends Composite implements AAAView {
interface AAAViewImplUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, AAAViewImpl> {
}

private static AAAViewImplUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create(AAAViewImplUiBinder.class);

private Presenter presenter;

@UiField
ValueBoxEditorDecorator<String> firstName;
public AAAViewImpl() {
    Widget rootElement = ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
    initWidget(rootElement);
}

@Override
public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
}


@Override
public Driver initializeDriver() {
    Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
    driver.initialize(this);
    return driver;
}
```

**AAAViewImpl.ui.xml**

```
<e:ValueBoxEditorDecorator ui:field="firstName">
<e:valuebox>
  <g:TextBox maxLength="16" width="100%"/>

  </e:valuebox>
</e:ValueBoxEditorDecorator>
```

How can I disable/enable firstName textbox in runtime? 
Or how get access to the inner textbox of ValueBoxEditorDecorator object?
Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `ui:field` attribute on the ValueBoxEditorDecorator, set it on the inner TextBox.  Then you can disable the TextBox by using:

```
firstName.setEnabled(false);
```